# Show data from cache and retrieve new items from the network with RxJava

Tags: android, caching, rx-java

I have an Android app that must work both online and offline.
The data is being retrieved from a REST endpoint and cached locally in a CouchDBLite instance.
The records can be modified both offline and online so I have some properties on my objects that I use to set an object as dirty or deleted. I won't get in the details of that as it's not pertinent, but this kind of behavior is part of the requirements.

I am currently using Retrofit 2 and RxJava 1.x and I came up with a working function to retrieve the data I need.

The flow should be along the following scheme:

```
         +------------------------------+
         |                              |
         |                              |
      +--v---+                          |
      |      |         +-----------+    |
+----->  UI  +---+----^+ DB getAll +----+
      |      |   |     +-----------+
      ++-----+   |
       ^         |
       |         ^
       |   +-----+------+
       |   | if canSync |
       |   +-----+------+
       |         | YES
       |         ^
       |  +------+--------+     +-----------+    +-----------+     +------------+    +----------+     +---------+
       |  | DB load DIRTY +----^+REST upload+---^+REST getAll+----^+set lastSync+---^+compare DB+----^+update DB|
       |  +---------------+     |DIRTY      |    +-----------+     +------------+    |lastUpdate|     +----+----+
       |                        +-----------+                                        +----------+          |
       |                                                                                                   |
       |                                                                                                   |
       |                                                                                            +------v------------+
       |                                                                                     YES    |DB getAll          |
       +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+returned 0 results?|
                                                                                                    +-------------------+
```

The flow above is based on the following rule:

- we return the data retrieved from the REST service only if there's no data already in the DB. That way we avoid
  refreshing the UI while the user is changing data. It's also handy to show a spinner while fetching the data from
  the service if there's no cached data.

Right now I'm trying to simplify the function that retrieves data and eventually make it generic so that I can just reuse it based on the type of the data I need to fetch. 
I'm having a hard time and a hand would really help.

Here's the function:

```
public Observable<List<MyTeam>> getAllMyTeam(final String idProfile) {
    return teamLocalRepository.getAllMyTeam(idProfile)
            .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<MyTeam>, Iterable<MyTeam>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<MyTeam> call(List<MyTeam> myTeams) {
                    return myTeams;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<MyTeam, Observable<MyTeam>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<MyTeam> call(final MyTeam team) {
                    return teamRemoteRepository.syncMyTeam(team);
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<MyTeam>, Observable<List<MyTeam>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<MyTeam>> call(List<MyTeam> myTeams) {
                    if (myTeams.size() == 0) {
                        // Return the data we fetch from the network
                        return teamRemoteRepository.getAllMyTeam(idProfile)
                                .map(new Func1<List<MyTeam>, List<MyTeam>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public List<MyTeam> call(List<MyTeam> myTeams) {
                                        return myTeams;
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        // Fire off a refresh from the network and ignore it
                        teamRemoteRepository.getAllMyTeam(idProfile)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe();
                        // Return the cached data
                        return Observable.just(myTeams);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**Update**

I tried my way to make it work with generics as I'd like to write just two methods, one for the single item and one for a list of items.
What I came up with for the list of items is the following, but I get a lot of `unchecked` warnings:

```
public Observable<List<T>> getAll(final Class<T> clazz, final Repository localRepo, final Repository remoteRepo, final String idProfile) {
    return localRepo.getAll(idProfile)
            .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<T>, Iterable<T>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<T> call(List<T> items) {
                    return Collections.checkedList(items, clazz);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<T>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<T> call(final T item) {
                    return remoteRepo.sync(item);
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<T>, Observable<List<T>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<T>> call(List<T> items) {
                    if (items.size() == 0) {
                        // Return the data we fetch from the network
                        return remoteRepo.getAll(idProfile)
                                .map(new Func1<List<T>, List<T>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public List<T> call(List<T> items) {
                                        return Collections.checkedList(items, clazz);
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        // Fire off a refresh from the network and ignore it
                        remoteRepo.getAll(idProfile)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe();
                        // Return the cached data
                        return Observable.just(items);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I guess that I could just suppress the unchecked warnings for that method, but maybe there's a better way.
On top of that I can't make `T extends SomeBaseClass` because the models come from `swagger-codegen` and it looks like there is no way to inherit the models from a custom made class and that makes things even harder because my `sync` method will need to check some properties of the model to actually work.

Comment: In similar cases I use http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchIfEmpty(rx.Observable) with '.doOnNext()' to cache data locally (i.e. get from cache/DB if present of from Retrofit if cache/db is empty and cache it afterwards). And the whole thing is wrapped in http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchOnNext(rx.Observable) where 'sequence of sequences' is a BehaviorSubject, to which you feed new calls to db/retrofit.

Comment: @MaximVolgin does `switchIfEmpty` still call the second observable if the first isn't empty? I still want to run the second (retrofit) to upload modified data and download new data if present, but avoid feeding it to the user right away

Comment: Nope, that it doesn't.